# Using regular expression to extract values that contain comma

Tags: c#, regex

I am working with a text such as this:

```
Graham, Mckenna -- ut    Voluptatem ipsam et at.Marvin, Garfield -- non    Facere et necessitatibus animi. McLaughlin, Mariah -- consequatur Eveniet temporibus ducimus amet eaque. Lang, Agustina -- pariatur
```

As you can see, valid English names are separated by comma and a space. I am looking for a regular expression pattern to extract such substring. Comma should be included in the substring but not the trailing white space. I haven't had much luck in finding the correct pattern yet.

my code in C# looks like this:

```
var value = reader.ReadLine();
var regex = new Regex(@"[A-Z]\w+,(?=\s)");
var match = regex.Match(value);
```

Comment: Well since you have had no luck with the correct pattern, perhaps show what you have tried.

Comment: How many parts can a name have? 1 or more, 2 or more, always 2?

Comment: Only two parts, last name, first name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to match the names before the comma and after the comma, you can use the following.

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+, *[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+");
```

Or you could simplify the pattern to the following in this case:

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"(?i)[a-z]+, *[a-z]+");
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/0G8zPH)

Answer (score 0):

If there's always exactly 2 name parts:

```
/[a-z]+, [a-z]+/i
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/DlfMeQrGQk) using your input.